# In an essay about three books: alternatives to "the three books here studied"?

Tags: phrase-request

In an essay about three books, there will obviously be repeated references to this set of three books.

What could be alternatives to "the three books here studied"?

Is something like "our three books" acceptable? Or too familiar?

Comment: If the reader already knows which books you are discussing, you can just refer to them as 'the three books'.

Comment: The three books discussed here. Here comes after the verb. Not before it.

Answer (score 1):

> The three books here studied

is stilted and awkward. Assuming you have initially named the books, you can refer to the three collectively in many natural ways without necessarily repeating that they are books or repeating that there are three of them:

> they
> the books
> the trio
> the three books
> these books
> this trio
> these three books
> this trio of books
> our books
> our trio
> our three books
> our trio of books

are just some examples. And of course you can create variety by repeating a title from time to time.

> Some what more frequent in “A Tale of Two Cities” than in the other two is …

English does not lack tools for creating variety that sounds natural.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The trouble with "they," "these books," or "the books," is that other books are mentioned throughout the essay, so that when referring to the three books that are the focus of the essay, there is a need to be more specific. Therefore, anything like "our three books" is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

An essay is a *personal* discourse on a topic.  It is up to you how familiar you want to make it. If you are consistent in the use of "we/our" then there is no error in saying "our books".